# Mouse position relative to sf::view

Tags: c++, sfml

I made a view centered on the avatar of the player sprite, and after 3 days of brain storming all I've got is (basically) this:

```
    xVeiwMouse = xWindowMouse - Playerx;//(new mouse coord) = (mouse coord relitive to window) - (playersprite coord)
    yVeiwMouse = yWindowMosue - Playery;//same, but with y
```

which doesn't work.

I need the mouse's coordinates relative to a view, centered on the player.

Comment: So I found MapPixelToCoords() i think that's what i need, but i have absolutely no idea how to use it, or where to implement it, i just know that it exists.

Comment: You might get better response on the official sfml forums.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but this might become handy: https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Source%3A-Zoom-View-At-%28specified-pixel%29

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
sf::Vector2f mouse_pos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
sf::Vector2f relative = player.getPosition() - mouse_pos;
```

Check the official documentation and tutorials for further explanations on the used functions.